# Dagger 2 - How @ContributesAndroidInjector behaves when another provision method depends on its return type

Tags: dagger-2, dagger

I have two provision methods, one depending on the object the other method provides. Below code works properly the problem is stated under the section of **Problem**

> Working Example

In **StringProviderModule**, added a method which is dependent on the object (`Fragment` instance) provided in the parent component.

```
@Module
class StringProviderModule {
    @Module
    companion object{
        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        fun provideFragmentArgument(cripledFragment: CripledFragment): String{
            return cripledFragment.arguments?.getString(CripledFragment.ARG_STRING) ?: "No such argument"
        }
    }
}
```

In **FragmentModule**, added **StringProviderModule** to **FragmentModule**'s generated subcomponent

```
@Module
abstract class FragmentModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [StringProviderModule::class])
    abstract fun fragment: CripledFragment
}
```

In **ActivityBinderModule**, adding **FragmentModule** to the **ActivityBinderModule**'s generated subcomponent

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBinderModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FragmentModule::class])
    abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

In **AppComponent**, adding **ActivityBinderModule** as a module

```
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, 
    ActivityBinderModule::class
])
interface AppComponent: AndroidInjector<DaggerMyApp> {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder{
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

Then `@Inject`ing String into `Presenter` class and `@Inject`ing that presenter into `CripledFragment`. I can access Fragment's String argument in Presenter. Implementation is not important as it's outside the scope of the question, I can add code if needed, though.

> Problem

When merging **StringProviderModule** and **FragmentModule**, IDE complains with following message "CripledFragment cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method". Isn't `@ContributesAndroidInjector` already providing an instance of `CripledFragment`?

```
@Module
abstract class FragmentModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun cripledFragment(): CripledFragment

    @Module
    companion object{

        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        fun provideFragmentArgument(cripledFragment: CripledFragment): String{
            return cripledFragment.arguments?.getString(CripledFragment.ARG_STRING) ?: "No such argument"
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked multiple tutorials and dagger docs, couldn't find any proper explanation to infer the cause of my problem. Simple explanation rather than suggesting a solution is much appreciated as I'm not looking for a concrete solution.

Comment: I don't see where you add the `FragmentModule.Companion` module, but I'm assuming you add it to the Activity component as well. You can't access `CripledFragment` from the Activity component, but you'll have to add the module to the fragment component, and you'll be able to access the fragment from there (`@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules=[FragmentModule.Companion::class] fun cripledFragment(): CripledFragment`)

Comment: @DavidMedenjak, I'm not adding it to anywhere, I mean inside `ActivityBinderModule` I'm adding `FragmentModule` like `@Module abstract class ActivityBinderModule{@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules =[FragmentModule::class])abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity}`. Which means both `FragmentModule` and `FragmentModule.Companion` will be modules of auto-generated `CripledFragmentSubcomponenet`. So, I should be able to access CripledFragment inside CripledFragmentSubcomponenet

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58712860/why-contributesandroidinjector-doesnt-provide-android-framework-type/58713143?noredirect=1#comment103720222_58713143). Basically, `@ContributesAndroidInjector` provides `MainActivity` instance for a subcomponent it generates not for a module (in this case `ActivityBinderModule`) it resides in. That means any provision method inside `FragmentModule` will have access to `MainActivity`'s instance.

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBinderModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FragmentModule::class])
    abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```