# Why @ContributesAndroidInjector doesn't provide Android Framework type

Tags: dagger-2, dagger

I have simplified my application to get the root of the problem and here is the simplified version. I'm implementing Dagger 2 using following configuration:

**AppComponent**

```
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    ActivityBindingModule::class
])
interface AppComponent: AndroidInjector<MyApp> {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder{
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

**ActivityBindingModule**

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity

    @Module
    companion object{
        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        fun provideString(mainActivity: MainActivity): String{
            return "Tent"
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var string: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        println("meco simplest ${string}")
    }
}
```

When I run the application I get the following error. What I don't understand is `ContributesAndroidInjector` is already providing an instace of `MainActivity` why Dagger still complains about it.

> MainActivity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an
>   @Provides-annotated method

**EDIT** for @yavor

Keep all classes as is and separate **ActivityBindingModule** implementation into two classes. Now you can see that instance of the `MainActivity` is provided and Dagger is not complaining about it.
**ActivityBindingModule**

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modulese [StringProviderModule::class])
    abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

**StringProviderModule**

```
@Module
class StringProviderModule {
    @Module
    companion object{
        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        fun provideString(mainActivity: MainActivity): String{
            return "Tent"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to inject your application in `MyApp`. You should have something like this (you might need to modify it a bit to fit your `AppComponent`:

```
DaggerAppComponent.builder()
    .application(this)
    .build()
    .inject(this)
```

Also, Dagger is actually providing your `MainActivity` through your `@ContributesAndroidInjector` annotated method but that's not what you're injecting.

You're injecting a `string` so Dagger is using your `provideString` method. Since this method requires a `MainActivity` instance to work, Dagger is looking for such a method annotated with `@Provides`. You don't have any and Dagger won't look at your `@ContributesAndroidInjector` method since it does not have any reasons to do so.

If you want it to work, you actually have to define your `provideString` method in a separate module and install it inside your `@ContributesAndroidInjector`:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [StringModule::class])
    abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity
}

@Module
class StringModule {

    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    fun provideString(mainActivity: MainActivity): String = "Hehe"
}
```

Comment: As I said I've simplified the application to find out that problem is actually in this section only. It works if I change `fun provideString(mainActivity: MainActivity): String{
            return "Hehe"
        }` to `fun provideString(): String{
            return "Hehe"
        }`. So, it's not the problem

Comment: @Farid I've just edited my answer but it seems like you found the problem yourself.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to find an answer to "Why @ContributesAndroidInjector doesn't provide Android Framework type" required by another provision method

Comment: It does provide the framework type for every module installed on the `@ContributesAndroidInjector` method. Here you ask the dependency from a module which is not installed on such an `@ContributesAndroidInjector`.

Comment: Yes, your last interpretation was much needed as I told @Yavor, he interpreted it just the same way. To be fair for you both, I'll upvote both answers without accepting. I hope it won't be a big deal and thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

*What I don't understand is ContributesAndroidInjector is already providing an instace of MainActivity why Dagger still complains about it.*

ContributesAndroidInjector in docs says:

**Generates an {@link AndroidInjector} for the return type of this method. The injector is implemented with a {@link dagger.Subcomponent} and will be a child of the {@link dagger.Module}'s component.**

So it does not provide MainActivity.

Why do you need it actually at all? I see that you are passing it as parameter to the function:

**fun provideString(mainActivity: MainActivity)**

but do you really need it there? In general you should inject dependencies in MainActivity. MainActivity should use them. If both(MainActivity and the string) they know about each other it is first - not a good design, and second: you are close to create cyclic dependencies which Dagger 2 does not support and throws exception.

Comment: Please see the gist of my question, I have simplified my project to find out the problem and the problem lies in this section. In a real implementation, I'm using an instance of `MainActivity` to get extras from intent. Also, see the **EDIT** section, if it didn't provide an instance Dagger should have been complaining again.

Comment: Also, this is not a circular dependency. Because injection doesn't happen when `MainActivity` object is created it's called after `onCreate` method is called. Circualar dependency happens when two objects `@Inject` each other when they're initialized

Comment: I would have to disagree with you: "In software engineering, a circular dependency is a relation between two or more modules which either directly or indirectly depend on each other to function properly. Such modules are also known as mutually recursive." So it is about the dependency and not how you create the dependency. Also I said that "you are about to create a circular dependency" as I see that the method is dummy, but I have no idea what you are really doing inside it. But I am still sure that whatever it is it is not a good design. Just create a method and call it passing the Intent

Comment: About your real question, and here I am really blurry to be honest and might say something stupid, but all these things generate something like a tree with a dependencies. So in the first case you have in the end: "two different nodes". All of the dependencies for MainActivity are in on branch and you can't pass this to the other "branch" where the method is generated. That is why it works in the second case: everything is in the same "branch". Hope it helps.

Comment: I've quite a harsh writing tone, sorry for that. You're totally right about circular dependency. Probably you're familiar with Dagger, but I'll just drop a few lines about it. Dagger uses a `Provider`, even two objects are in circular dependency Dagger will create ObjectA and will inject ObjectB and in case of ObjectB, it will inject ObjectA only when ObjectB requires ObjectA's instance. So, In the case of Activity, requirement happens in `onCreate` of `Activity` so Dager can easily inject String into Activity.

Comment: The last is complicated topic. I really don't to argue about it. I am really trying to help. About Dagger: I have read a lot of articles, but I am still blurry on how everything works under the hood, but I will actually make second "guess". You will have in the generated code a component providing the String and a child component of it will be the one for MainAcitivity. So I assume that this is the problem. You can't provide something from the child in the parent. *Totally guessing*, but really from some experience.

Comment: Yes, I think I needed interpretation for this "Generates an {@link AndroidInjector} for the return type of this method. The injector is implemented with a {@link dagger.Subcomponent} and will be a child of the {@link dagger.Module}'s component." and you provided it in the last comment. The other answer interprets the same thing in their last comment. So, to be fair for both of you, I'll upvote both answers without accepting. And thanks

Comment: You are welcome. I hope you will succeed in the end :) Thank you too! :)